# How to make responsively sized images retain their relative position in fluid design?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, absolute

I am trying to create a gallery that consists of different sized photographs arranged "randomly", in a scrapbook style.

In order to do this, I built a grid, consisting of three columns and six rows. I then placed the images where I wanted them, using absolute positioning.

By specifying the width as a percentage and omitting the height, I was able to make them scale responsively.

However, as the screen size gets smaller, the images drift farther and farther away from each other.

I want the images to scale down whilst maintaining their relative ration between the other elements. An example of this can be seen on this site: https://andy-irwin.com/Home

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="gallerycont">

<div class="column1">

<div class="a1" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1000">
<img src="pics/1c0ba4af387d4cc8187b564f8843dcb8.jpg" alt="">

</div>

<div class="a2">

</div>

<div class="a3">

</div>

<div class="a4">

</div>

<div class="a5">

</div>

<div class="a6" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1000">
<img src="pics/6.jpg" alt="">

</div>


</div>


<div class="column2">

  <div class="b1">

  </div>

  <div class="b2" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1500">
<img src="pics/3.jpg" alt="">

  </div>

  <div class="b3">

  </div>

  <div class="b4" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1000">
<img src="pics/4.jpg" alt="">

  </div>

  <div class="b5">

  </div>

  <div class="b6">

  </div>

</div>


<div class="column3">

  <div class="c1">

  </div>

  <div class="c2" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="2000">
<img src="pics/2.jpg" alt="">

  </div>

  <div class="c3">

  </div>

  <div class="c4">

  </div>

  <div class="c5">

  </div>

  <div class="c6">

  </div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

````
.gallerycont {
  width:100%;
  height: 2000px;
  position:absolute;
  top:80px;
  /* background-color: lavenderblush; */

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow:row nowrap;
z-index: 2;
}

.column1, .column2, .column3 {
  width:33.33%;
  height:2000px;
  /* background-color: red; */

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow:column nowrap;
}

.column1 {
  background-color: lavender;
}

.column2 {
  background-color: mistyrose;
}

.column3 {
  background-color: palevioletred;
}

.a1, .a2, .a3, .a4, .a5, .a6 {
  height:25%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.b1, .b2, .b3, .b4, .b5, .b6 {
  height:25%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4, .c5, .c6 {
  height:525%;
  width:100%;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.a1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.a1 img {
  width:70%;

}

.a6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  position:relative;
}

.a6 img {
  width:120%;
position:absolute;
left:100px;
}


.c2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  position:relative;
}

.c2 img {
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:10px;
  z-index:5
}

.b2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  position:relative;
}

.b2 img {
  width:70%;
  position:absolute;
  top:-70px;

}

.b4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: baseline;
  position:relative;
}

.b4 img {
  width:160%;
  position:absolute;
  top:-70px;

}```
  



I hope I have explained this clearly, I'm very new at this. Thank you!
````